# JavaScript: src method returns empty string

Tags: javascript, domparser

When using src method to get URL, it returns empty string like this:

```
// returns whole url example
var d1 = new DOMParser().parseFromString("<html><body><script id='hoge' src='http://stackoverflow.com/'></script></body></html>", "text/html");
d1.getElementById('hoge').src; // "http://stackoverflow.com/"
// returns empty string example
var d2 = new DOMParser().parseFromString("<html><body><script id='hoge' src='//stackoverflow.com'></script></body></html>", "text/html");
d2.getElementById('hoge').src; // ""
```

I used getElementById and src, but some src can return whole url, but others can return empty string.

It is because there is no protocol in src element. But I have no idea why src method returns empty string.

Could you tell me why?

Comment: Can't reproduce on Firefox. The second seems to use the scheme of the page that runs the script.

Comment: @Oriol I can reproduce in Chrome. `d2.getElementById("hoge").src` is the empty string and `d2.getElementById("hoge").getAttribute("src")` correctly reports the value.

Comment: Looks like the `new DOMParser` DOM doesn't know its document location so it cannot resolve relative urls. Not sure how to fix that though.

Comment: I am not sure why, but adding http/https protocol on src attribute solves my problem.

Comment: @Oriol I got src your code. Thanks so much!